# PDFsharp - XStringFormatFlags missing in newer version

Tags: c#, .net, pdfsharp, migradoc

A project I'm currently working on uses MigraDoc and PDFsharp. So far it used the latest stable version, 1.32.2608, but we are trying to migrate to a newer, prerelease version (because of a connected project using 1.50.4619-beta4c). And almost everything looks fine, but there is one thing I'm not sure how to get around.
There is a function measuring a string's size, looking (to put it simply) something about that:

```
protected SSize GetSize(string text, MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Font font)
{
  var doc = new PdfDocument();
  var page = doc.AddPage;
  var sizer = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
  var style = XFontStyle.Regular;
  //some style checks

  var xf = new XFont(font.Name, font.Size, style);
  var st = new XStringFormat();
  st.FormatFlags = XStringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;
  var xs = sizer.MeasureString(text, xf, st);
  return new SSize {
    Height = XUnit.FromPoint(xs.Height * _measureCorrection).Centimeter,
    Width = XUnit.FromPoint(xs.Width * _measureCorrection).Centimeter
  };
}
```

and the problematic line is:

```
st.FormatFlags = XStringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;
```

as the XStringFormat lost the FormatFlags property, and there is no longer the XStringFormatFlags enum.
Does anyone have any similar experience and could give a clue, how to transform it properly to a new version?

Comment: Question was answered in the official PDFsharp forum: https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=12041#p12041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the official PDFsharp forum you can find this implementation of a `TextMeasurement` class that appears to be much more efficient than your code snippet above:
https://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3196
Your code creates a new PDF document and a new PDF page just to measure a string - for every string.

To deal with trailing spaces:

- One option is measuring the spaces separately - measure "X X" and "XX" and use the difference as the width of a space.
- Or append "X" to every string and subtract the width of "X" afterwards to get the width of the string with trailing spaces.

You can take the `TextMeasurement` class to get started and save the width of "X" or " " respectively inside the class to get a more efficient implementation.